# Como criar array aninhado a partir de informações recebidas via POST

Tags: php, array, lógica

Dado o array abaixo:

```
$aDup = array(
    array('35342-1','2016-06-20','300.00'),
    array('35342-2','2016-07-20','300.00'),
    array('35342-3','2016-08-20','300.00'),
    array('35342-4','2016-09-20','300.00')
);
```

Criei algo como:

```
for($i=0; $i<$dados['dados']['n-parcelas']; $i++){
    $val .= "array('".$id."-".($i+1)."','".$dados['dados']['vencimento-parcela'][$i]."','".$dados['dados']['parcela'][$i]."'),";
}
$val = substr($val, 0, -1);
$aDup = array($val);
```

Mas, sem sucesso.

As informações deverão alimentar as seguintes variáveis:

```
foreach ($aDup as $dup) {
        $nDup = $dup[0]; // Código da Duplicata
        $dVenc = $dup[1]; // Vencimento
        $vDup = $dup[2]; // Valor
        $resp = $nfe->tagdup($nDup, $dVenc, $vDup);
}
```

Comment: O primeiro código não resulta no terceiro? não entendi o objeto nem como deve ser feita essa 'conversão', poderia dar mais detalhes;?

Comment: Quero pegar o primeiro código e "criá-lo" utilizando informações recebidas via `$_POST`. @rray

Comment: Coloca um `print_r()` do `$_POST` na pergunta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se é `array` não precisa fazer uma `string`, faz tudo na `array` mesmo:

```
$arraySaida = array();

for ($i = 0; $i < $dados['dados']['n-parcelas']; $i++) {
    $arraySaida[] = array(
                       $id.'-'. ($i+1),
                       $dados['dados']['vencimento-parcela'][$i],
                       $dados['dados']['parcela'][$i]
                    );
}

print_r($arraySaida);
```

Note que o `$arraySaida[]` funciona semelhante ao [`array_push()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php), é adicionado um `array` dentro do `array` da variável `$arraySaida`